# Is it possible to change the "in:" for incollections to "In:" in the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Good morning everybody,

is it possible to change the "in:" in the picture below to "In:"?
[image]

Edit:
I am using this setup with some extra configurations:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear,
maxcitenames=3, 
maxbibnames=999,
date=iso,
seconds=true, 
urldate=iso,
innamebeforetitle,
dashed=false,
autocite=footnote,
doi=true,
useprefix=true,
mincrossrefs = 1
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your screenshot and do not forget to add the used bib entry to your question!

Comment: With the settings you show I'd expect the entry in the screenshot to show a capitalised "In:" provided it comes from a straightforward `.bib` entry. We can only help you if you show us a fully compilable example document that reproduces the output from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{. In:}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that works for you and thank you for getting back here and telling other people about the solution.

Comment: Other readers please note that this quite radical redefinition disables `biblatex`'s localisation feature for "in" and also does not use the punctuation buffer/tracker, which means that undesirable punctuation is more likely. At least from the code shown in the question so far it is not at all clear why code like this would be needed anyway. `biblatex` will automatically capitalise the "in" unless ordered otherwise.